# Opencsv How to Parse and Process Individual Row?

Tags: java, opencsv

When I parse my csv file of 20k rows using CsvToBeanBuilder my app runs out of memory.  So I now want to parse each individual row into my pojo and then process them one by one.

Can I do that with CsvToBeanBuilder?

Comment: The [Reading into beans](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#reading_into_beans) documentation indicates [`CsvToBean#iterator()`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.opencsv/opencsv/5.9/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBean.html#iterator--) does what you want.